# On edit function with more than one letter

Tags: javascript

I created a bit of code, that has the On edit function.
So when others types "x" it gives me a timestamp in another cell.
Some are working on the google sheets app, and it gives you an "X" to start with

Is there anyway to get the On edit function to also work woth the large "X"?

I tried == "x","X", but then it also inserted a timestamp everytime i changed anything in the cell..

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
 if (sheet.getName() ==
 "Mandagstræning","Tirsdagstræning","Torsdagstræning","Holdkamp") {
var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange();
var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, editColumn, 1,
sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf("Tid") + editColumn;
if (sheet.getRange(rowIndex, orderCol).getValue() === "x") {
sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new
Date(), "UTC+8", "dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm.ss"));
}
```

No error message, just no time stamp when hitting "X"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just want this check to be case insensitive.  To accomplish this you can simply [lowercase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) the input before checking it against "x", like so:

```
if (sheet.getRange(rowIndex, orderCol).getValue().toLowerCase() === "x") {
  sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new
  Date(), "UTC+8", "dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm.ss"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//++
const keyss = ['x','X'];

function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
 if (sheet.getName() ==
 "Mandagstræning","Tirsdagstræning","Torsdagstræning","Holdkamp") {
var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange();
var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, editColumn, 1,
sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf("Tid") + editColumn;

// edited -->
if ( keyss.includes(sheet.getRange(rowIndex, orderCol).getValue())) {
sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new
Date(), "UTC+8", "dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm.ss"));
}
```